# Angular 2 - Best way to make a class globally accessible

Tags: angular

Which is the best way to declare a class global in angular 2, without the need of importing it's on each component? I would like to use it from the view too: for example {{GlobalClass.someMessage}}

Comment: Just import it everywhere. What's the problem with importing? You get proper auto-completion, type-checking, ...

Comment: The problem is when I use it from the view. Do you see any problem attaching it to window object?

Comment: You need a variable or getter in the component that points to the class. You can only access members of the component class in the view.

Comment: Yes that's my problem... so there is not way to define a variable with global scope in angular?

Comment: You can just use a static field on any class, but you need to import that class where you want to use it. This doesn't mean you can't do it. And you can't access static variables from a view directly.

Comment: Ok that is what I wanted to know :(,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Attach the class to `Window` object. Then add the class name to `typings.d.ts`.

Comment: I can´t access to it, even ataching the class to Window object.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class that all classes you want extends from this class like this...

```
export default class Ext {
  testMethod = ()=>{
   Console.log("blah blah");
 };
}
```

And you need import **Ext** class in your module that you need,

```
export default class test extend Ext{
 Contractor(){
         this.testMethod();
 }
}
```

Another way without importing that,you can use from **window** object.